# The logarithm of the p-quantile

Tags: statistics, functions, probability-distributions

Maybe somebody can explain how to get this result: [image]

it's the logarithm of the p-quantile for the Weibull distribution. I actually know the formula of the Weibull distribution and that the Survival function has this form:
[image]

but still don't know how to get the result above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantile $x(p)$ satisfies $$\Pr[T > x(p)] = 1-p \tag{1}$$ where $T$ is Weibull with survival function $$S_T(t) = e^{-(t/\eta)^\nu}. \tag{2}$$  But the survival function literally is $$S_T(t) = \Pr[T > t].$$  So combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ (where I have abbreviated $x(p)$ to $x$) yields $$e^{-(x/\eta)^\nu} = 1 - p,$$ and we need to solve for $x$:  $$\left(\frac{x}{\eta}\right)^\nu = -\log (1-p),$$ hence $$\nu \log \frac{x}{\eta} = \log (- \log(1-p) ),$$ and $$\log x - \log \eta = \frac{1}{\nu} \log ( - \log(1-p) ),$$ therefore the log-quantile $$\gamma(p; \boldsymbol \theta) = \log x(p) = \log \eta + \frac{1}{\nu} \log ( - \log(1-p) )$$ as claimed.

Comment: Thanks. So as I understand, you in my formula above wrote $p$ instead of $F(t)$, but for not all distributions $\Pr[T > x(p)] = 1-p$ will have this form. For, example, how it looks for Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 1):

$$p=1-e^{-(\frac{t}{\eta})^v}$$

... solve it in $log (t)$

$$1-p=e^{-\Big(\frac{t}{\eta}\Big)^v}$$

$$-log(1-p)=\Big(\frac{t}{\eta}\Big)^v$$

$$log(-log(1-p))=v[log(t)-log(\eta)]$$

$$log(t)=\frac{1}{v}[log(-log(1-p))]+log(\eta)$$

... as claimed

Comment: Thanks. So as I understand, you in my survival function formula above wrote p instead of F(t), but for not all distributions Pr[T>x(p)]=1−p. For, example, how it looks for Poisson distribution? @tommik